# How to Handle Timezones and Daylight Saving Time in MongoDB Application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql, dst, moment-timezone

I'm currently working on a project where I save Datetime in a MongoDB. However, I'm facing some challenges when it comes to dealing with timezones and daylight saving time for users from different regions. Right now, I'm using Moment JS to handle time-related operations, but I want to make sure I'm following industry standards and best practices to handle this in a smooth and professional way.

Example Scenarios:

Displaying times in the user's local time-zone: I'd like to show timestamps in their local time-zone, even though I currently save all times in UTC.

Dealing with Daylight Saving Time: I want the system to automatically adjust for daylight saving time changes when scheduling events, so that the time representation stays accurate.

Deal with storing dateTime in MongoDB along with time-zone, so when it is being retrieved to display even daylight saving are considered.

Should I stick with Moment JS, or are there better alternatives or additional libraries that provide better support for these requirements? I'm also curious about how to implement these features effectively within my MongoDB-based application.

If anyone could offer some guidance, share some code examples, or point me to relevant resources, I'd really appreciate it.

This is just a start of my research, expecting to get a big picture idea

Comment: normally, I saved in the DB as UTC, and then I ask in the user profile, what timezone he in, and do the calculations on the frontend... makes things easy and simple

Comment: Here are some ideas from the MongoDB website about [modelling time data](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/model-time-data/).

Answer (score 1):

The most important point is to store `Date` objects, not strings. Then the timestamps are always stored as UTC time and typically the client application is responsible to display these values in local format and local time zone.

Moment.js is deprecated, there are not further developments. In long term, you should migrate to another library, e.g. [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/) or [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon). It's a matter of taste, which one you use. My favorite is Luxon, because I don't like to load all the plugins one by one. In a MongoDB server script, the size of a script and bandwidth does not matter. Luxon applies stronger to ISO-8601 standards (see for example https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1729).